# With QT, How to remove warning : 'qInitResources_RessourceMedia__init_variable__' defined but not used

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt 4.8 project with a resource file named RessourceMedia.qrc. Everything works just fine except for this warning :

> /MyProjectPath/qrc_RessourceMedia.cpp:27104: warning: 'qInitResources_RessourceMedia__init_variable__' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
> Q_CONSTRUCTOR_FUNCTION(QT_MANGLE_NAMESPACE(qInitResources_RessourceMedia))

I've read it could be some unused resources:

- I got rid of the unused resources
- I even tried to used them in a dummy way like `QPixmap(":PICTURES/MyIcon.png");` for all files listed in RessourceMedia.qrc

I tried to init the resources in the main like that :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(RessourceMedia);
    [...]
```

I still have this warning, the only one, which is very upsetting as my client requests 0 warning.

Would somebody help me ?

Comment: If no one knows how to really suppress this warning, does someone would know how I can hide it ? I obviously don't want to hide all Wunused, but if I could for just this warning, it would be good. But it might be impossible as it's inside qt generated code ...